# \thispagestyle not working with \cleardoubleoddpage

Tags: koma-script, pagestyle

I have a twoside document and when I add

```
\cleardoubleoddpage
\thispagestyle{scrheadings}
```

the resulting empty page has no headers like the page before.

How can I get the headers on this new page too?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside, openany]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{a4paper, includefoot, include head}
 \usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage} 

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
 
\clearpairofpagestyles
 
\makeatletter \let\ps@plain\ps@scrheadings \makeatother 

\ihead{\headmark}
 \automark*{chapter} \automark*[section]{}
 \ohead{\pagemark}
 
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 
 \begin{document}   
\chapter{Test}  
\section{Test}  
\lipsum
\cleardoubleoddpage     
\thispagestyle{scrheadings} 
\chapter{Test 2}
\section{Test 2}    
\lipsum 
\end{document}
```

This is my first MWE, if there is anything missing or to much, please let me know.

Comment: Please extend this to a full but minimal example others can copy and test as is. Please to realise that without a full example, we mostly have no idea what you are referring to

Comment: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228

Comment: I added the MWE as requested.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific as to what exactly it is you want the first two lines to do? What is your end goal here?

Comment: I further narrowed the MWE a little bit down, which lines do you mean?

The end goal is to have the header as seen in the document on the empty page generated by \cleardoubleoddpage (so chapter/section title, page number as well as the line under the header.

Comment: On my compute, when building your MWE, the \cleardoubleoddpage does nothing. (Chapter 1 already ends on an even page.)

Comment: You can replace `\cleardoubleoddpage` by `\cleardoubleoddstandardpage` or `\cleardoubleoddpageusingstyle{scrheadings}`. If all blank pages should use page style `scrheadings`: set class option `cleardoublepage=scrheadings` or class option `cleardoublepage=current` and use `\cleardoubleoddpage`.
But in your MWE there is no such blank page.

Comment: @esdd: that should be _the_ answer. Mind making it so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The KOMA-Script class uses option `cleardoublepage=empty` by default. Therefore blank pages inserted by `\cleardoublepage` or `\cleardoubleoddpage` etc. get page style `empty`.

You can change this behaviour globally using option `cleardoublepage=current` or `cleardoublepage=<pagestyle>`, eg. `cleardoublepage=scrheadings`:

```latex
\documentclass[twoside,open=any,cleardoublepage=current]{scrreprt}% or cleardoublepage=scrheadings
```

or

```latex
\documentclass[twoside,open=any]{scrreprt}
\KOMAoptions{cleardoublepage=scrheadings}% or cleardoublepage=current
```

If only one blank page should use a different page style, replace `\cleardoubleoddpage` by `\cleardoubleoddstandardpage` or `\cleardoubleoddpageusingstyle{scrheadings}`.

Additional remarks:

```latex
\automark*{chapter} \automark*[section]{}
```

does the same as

```latex
\automark[section]{chapter}
```

Maybe you want

```latex
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\automark*[section]{}
```

Remove the redefinition of `\ps@plain`.

Maybe you want

```latex
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}% chapter pages get style scrheadings
```

or

```latex
\usepackage[headsepline,plainheadsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets page style scrheadings automatically
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\automark*[section]{}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead*{\headmark}% or \ihead[\headmark]{\headmark}, ie. same content for plain.scrheadings and scrheadings
\ohead*{\pagemark}% or \ohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}, ie. same content for plain.scrheadings and scrheadings
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[twoside, open=any,headinclude,footinclude,cleardoublepage=current]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[automark,headsepline,plainheadsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets page style scrheadings automatically
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead*{\headmark}% or \ihead[\headmark]{\headmark}, ie. same content for plain.scrheadings and scrheadings
\ohead*{\pagemark}% or \ohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}, ie. same content for plain.scrheadings and scrheadings

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\lipsum[1-2]
\cleardoubleoddpage
\chapter{Test 2}
\section{Test 2}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much, everything you wrote worked like a charm!

Is there any possibility to get rid of the \headmark on the first page for each the top, lof and lot?
Or should I better pose this as a separate question?

Comment: On the first page of all chapters: remove the `*` after `\ihead` : `\ihead{\headmark}`. If you really mean the first page of only ToC, LoF and LoT, then ask a new question.